# Can I set consumer group parameters in PrestoDB?

Tags: apache-kafka, presto

I use prestodb to query data on kafka. İt works well.

But every time it goes full to kafka every time. Can I set filter when I go to kafka.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you want? You shouldn't need a group id as each query should be scanning the whole topic. In other words, if you commit offsets, then each query would return different results and where there is no lag, you get no results... You can try adding a WHERE clause for filtering, sure. If you want something else, I don't think Presto is a good solution

Comment: When I run query on presto to select data from kafka, I want to put filter just get data for 2 days but as my understanding presto get all data and filter it on itself, so how can i optimize this? thanks

Comment: Okay, well, there's no way I know of that'll seek to any specific point in time, so are you able to add a WHERE clause on the record timestamp?

Comment: I put where clause in my query on prestodb but it gets all data and filter. Is there any way to put where clause when at the begining so we get filtered data from kafka

Comment: Like I said, there isn't a way to seek the consumer group. You would need to read all data, deserialize it, then filter